# How to output time field in lightning component

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, javascript, query, time

I have used a time field which I want to show in a lightning component

When I fill 8:00 in my field my result is 30600000 in my lightning component. I have searched for a time tag or formatting but could not find any explanation

Below the part of my lightning component

```
<td data-label="">
     <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
         {!Training.Starttime__c}
     </div>
</td>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [Formatted Date Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedDateTime/example) `<lightning:formattedDateTime>` or [Formatted Time](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/bundle/lightning:formattedTime/documentation) `<lightning:formattedTime>` component to display a formatted time value.

**Your Code using the Formatted Time component would be as below.**

```
 <td data-label="">
       <div class="slds-truncate" title="">
           <lightning:formattedTime value="{!Training.Starttime__c}" />
       </div>
 </td>
```

You could also use the `lightning:outputField` if you want to display the field type as is on the ***Sobject*** record.

Comment: Di you know what timezone this uses?

Comment: Formatted Time component displays a read-only representation of time in the user's locale format. A valid ISO8601 formatted time string must be used.

Comment: @JigarShah I tried all of the above with central europe summertime amsterdam but this doe not outpu anything with 8:00

Comment: Salesforce uses the format HH:mm:ss.SSSZ for time fields. The time field is a timestamp without the date included. Time values in Salesforce are not localized or associated with a time zone.

Comment: This answer is not usefull! Why is this marked as solution.